# Yii Table Prefix Cannot read table with that prefix

Tags: php, yii, frameworks, prefix

I started develop in localhost, using yii 1.1.11 using the auto generate app, create users table, using gii to generate crud. When I migrate to webhosting, I have to use prefix for the table thus become "yii_users" and edit the config with this:

```
'db'=>array(
  'connectionString' => 'xxxxx',
  'username' => 'xxxxx',
  'password' => 'xxxxx',
  'tablePrefix' => 'yii_',
),
```

But I can no longer login and get error 'The table "users" for active record class "Users" cannot be found in the database. ' So I assume the tablePrefix doesn't work. How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This requires you to change all your activerecords also, [check the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#defining-ar-class):

> Info: To use the table prefix feature, the tableName() method for an AR class may be overridden ...
>   ......
>   That is, instead of returning the fully qualified table name, we return the table name without the prefix and enclose it in double curly brackets

So you will need to do this:

```
public function tableName() {
    return '{{user}}';
}
```

Also from [`tablePrefix` doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#tablePrefix-detail):

> By setting this property, any token like '**{{tableName}}**' ... will be replaced by 'prefixTableName', where 'prefix' refers to this property value.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Ok You have given me the clue, so a gii generated model should have a method called "public function tableName()" I can either put in full string of table name or using curly bracket as you said. But as soon as I use curly bracket, the db config in main.php must have 'tablePrefix'. So even without prefix but using curly, 'tablePrefix' must be set with empty string. Its kinda troublesome if there are alot of models already and have to add that curly in every model.

Comment: yup, that's right, and i don't see it happening any other way atm. But if you want to use a tablePrefix, and you haven't yet generated your models, you can modify the model template (that gii uses for model generation) to use the curly braces by default. I haven't tried it yet, so not sure about the best way to do it.